# Copy specific range to first available row in another worksheet and transpose

Tags: vba, excel

The code below runs smoothly, and copies the data from Workbook1 to Workbook2 on the first available row, starting from column B. I need to know when the data was submitted, and therefore want the time and date to be inserted into the first available cell in column A each time data is submtited. Thanks for your help!

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveData()

'Define variables
Dim Workbook1 As Workbook
Dim Workbook2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long

'Set wb
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Copy (In this case I want to copy range D4:D7 only, and this will be the same every time)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D7").Copy

'Open Workbook 2 and paste data (transposed) on first available row starting in column B
Set Workbook2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Macro FSC\Forsøk10\Workbook2.xlsm")
With Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in destination workbook "Workbook2.xlsm"
    DestLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
     'paste special only values, and transpose
    .Range("B" & DestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True
End With

'Save and close
Workbook2.Save
Workbook2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, do you just want the date the transfer was made from workbook1 to workbook2? (i.e. the date the macro was run)? If so you can use something like Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()

Comment: That is correct. However, I think that formula is dynamic, i.e. it will show the current time and not the time the data transfer took place?

Comment: it would do if it was a formula in the workbook, but this is saying "the time is 17:05: make the value of this cell 17:05", rather than constantly reevaluating a formula over again.

Comment: Its true to say that the formula is dynamic (to 'Now' date), however the value it places in cell(1, 1) is not (as it just pastes in the result into the cell as opposed to the formula). If the date only need to be added under a certain circumstance when the macro is run, you could wrap it in an if block with the condition being based on a vbYesNo message box (ie something like "would you like to update the time stamp?" Yes or no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's a one line solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveData()

'Define variables
Dim Workbook1 As Workbook
Dim Workbook2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long

'Set wb
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Copy (In this case I want to copy range D4:D7 only, and this will be the same every time)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D7").Copy

'Open Workbook 2 and paste data (transposed) on first available row starting in column B
Set Workbook2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Macro FSC\Forsøk10\Workbook2.xlsm")
With Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in destination workbook "wbDatabase.xlsm"
    DestLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
     'paste special only values, and transpose
    .Range("B" & DestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True
'Added line here:
    .range("A1").Value = now
End With

'Save and close
Workbook2.Save
Workbook2.Close

End Sub
```